# Removing MySQL Orphan Tables in Google's Managed MySQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I have a number of orphan tables that I am unable to remove in Google managed MySQL instance.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html describes how to find them
using the query: 
`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLES WHERE NAME LIKE '%#sql%';`

and returns the following results

```
TABLE_ID, NAME, FLAG, N_COLS, SPACE, FILE_FORMAT, ROW_FORMAT, ZIP_PAGE_SIZE, SPACE_TYPE
'10790334', 's/#sql-ib10651620-992396264', '33', '10', '15069', 'Barracuda', 'Dynamic', '0', 'Single'
'11386494', 's/#sql-ib11176578-758128583', '33', '10', '15865', 'Barracuda', 'Dynamic', '0', 'Single'
'11715795', 's/#sql-ib11550885-968245244', '33', '56', '16593', 'Barracuda', 'Dynamic', '0', 'Single'
'11884112', 's/#sql-ib11854996-1155811138', '33', '63', '16936', 'Barracuda', 'Dynamic', '0', 'Single'
'12648506', 's/#sql-ib11883996-1143057998', '33', '31', '18549', 'Barracuda', 'Dynamic', '0', 'Single'
'12877658', 's/#sql-ib11884055-1196159549', '33', '34', '19856', 'Barracuda', 'Dynamic', '0', 'Single'
'15159365', 's/#sql-ib15000139-4079941189', '33', '58', '24560', 'Barracuda', 'Dynamic', '0', 'Single'
```

I am unable to select any of these tables, for example:

`` use s; SELECT * FROM `#mysql50##sql-ib10651620-992396264` limit 10 ``;

Following https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/get-rid-of-orphaned-innodb-temporary-tables-the-right-way/, 
I tried creating a table with the same name.

I figured out which tables these orphans came from with help from the query

SELECT * FROM
 `information_schema`.`innodb_sys_tables`
 JOIN `information_schema`.`innodb_sys_columns` USING (TABLE_ID)
 WHERE `information_schema`.`innodb_sys_tables`.`NAME` LIKE '%#sql%'

I then copied the create table statement for the related table and edited the table name.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `s`.`#sql-ib10651620-992396264` ( `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ...) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and then tried to drop it

```sql
drop table `s`.`#mysql50##sql-ib10651620-992396264`;
```

but it could not find the table.  After dropping the created table with

```sql
drop table `#sql-ib10651620-992396264`;
```

the orphan table still persists.

To my knowledge, with a managed MySQL instance, I do not have access to the machine that MySQL is running on and therefore cannot remove the associated files from the command line.  Logging into the database from the command line and executing a shell command, executes a command on the client's host system, not the system that MySQL is hosted on.

Not a huge issue, but it would be nice to reclaim this disk space.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with sw development, this is pure db admin stuff. Therefore this question is off topic here on SO. You may get more help at the DBA sister site of SO.

Comment: File a bug with bugs.mysql.com and with Google.

Answer (score 1):

Your theory is correct about your cloudSQL since it is a [Google managed service](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/).

If you would like to have full access over your mysql database, you can use it through a [Compute Engine instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-compute-engine) in which you will have super user privileges.

Nevertheless, about your current issue please fill a bug [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491274&template=1161130) which is under a private component and you can share if there is a need, sensitive information.